# Fetch line which contains only some specific symbol and number

Tags: text-processing, grep

I Need only those records from below file which contains Symbol like "+" and number and characters.

```
285627
AA283244
278178##
295456+
asdfasdf{
asdfasdfasdf
```

I tried below code but it gives all records

```
grep -E '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' temp.txt
```

I need only those records which contains either letters or number or `+` sign. If any record contains any other characters then it should be discarded. Record number 3 and 5 should not come in result:

```
285627
AA283244
295456+
asdfasdfasdf
```

Comment: Welcome to the U&L SE. There's only one entry in your question that has a the '+' character in it. Is that the only type of pattern (6 digits followed by a '+') or do you have other patterns you want to look for?

Comment: I Need only those records which contains either letters or Number or + sign. If any record contains any other characters then it should be discarded.

Comment: Every line there contains "characters "; which ones exactly do you want to include or exclude?

Comment: Rather than provide relevant details in comments, you should [edit] the question to improve its quality. I came across this question because it had been nominated for closure due to its lack of clarity. I voted to keep it open and edited  it for you -- but you should really do this yourself. See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Remove any line that contains a character that is not (a letter or number or `+`):

```
grep -v '[^[:alnum:]+]' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `+` in your character list. The plus after the `[...]` is the quantifier (1 or more of the before mentioned character group).

Also you must enclose it in `^` for start of line and `$` for end of line, as otherwise you will also match parts of each line, e.g. `278178` from `278178##`.

Try this,

```
grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9+]+$' temp.txt
```

Comment: You could add `-i` and simplify your pattern a bit.

Comment: Sure the pattern is not very good. My intend was to fix OPs pattern and not to provide the best one. You made it with your answer anyways ;-)